# 'Wine' is not available in Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: wine

according to [this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tBchXITQM5g), WINE is supposed to be in the Ubuntu Software Center. However, I cannot find it there:

[image]

I have Ubuntu 18.04 LTS installed.

Comment: Do you have the 'universe' repo enabled? If not, try searching after [enabling it](https://askubuntu.com/q/148638/480481) and then report back.

Comment: Not an answer - but [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/announce/5.7) is listed in the [Ubuntu Repo](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=wine&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) here, so I second @pomsky comment :)

Comment: In the terminal, after typing 'sudo add-apt-repository universe', I get the message '' 'universe' distribution component is already enabled for all sources.''

Comment: Hi, does anybody have an idea?